# Windows Batch: Cannot copy file using "if exist" + argument?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the file `dummyfile.txt` in the root of `C:\` and I want to copy it to my desktop with this:

```
@echo off
if exist %1 copy %systemdrive%\%1 "%userprofile%\desktop"
```

The name of the batch file is `copy.bat`, so I'm using `copy.bat dummyfile.txt` in CMD, but it doesn't work.

I can copy it with this though:

```
copy %systemdrive%\dummyfile.txt "%userprofile%\desktop"
```

and with this:

```
if exist %systemdrive%\dummyfile.txt copy %systemdrive%\dummyfile.txt "%userprofile%\desktop"
```

The below also says "The file exists":

```
So, where's the mistake in
@echo off
if exist "%systemdrive%\dummyfile.txt" (
  echo The file exists
) else (
    echo The file does not exist
  )
```

Why is this? What's wrong with my script that uses an argument?

Comment: When you say `if exist %1 copy %systemdrive%\%1 "%userprofile%\desktop"` where are you expecting it to look to see if the file exists there?  Are you sure you shouldn't say `if exist %systemdrive%\%1 copy %systemdrive%\%1 "%userprofile%\desktop"`

Comment: If you drag and drop the file onto your script, does it work as expected?

Comment: @Jerry Jeremiah Yeah, that's a legit question. Plus, your example (when stating explicitly what and where to look for) works fine! I'm actually not sure how it should be, I was following the video in which the author did just as in my example (but he was using XP). You can watch it for yourself here (it's about 30 sec): https://imgur.com/a/j7kTNap

Comment: @SomethingDark I'm not sure I understood the question. Did you mean to drop the file onto the `.bat` file icon in the explorer? I so, then I've just tried it. Nothing.

Comment: Is the batch script also in C:\ or is it in some other directory? Providing a filename without a drive or path makes the script look in the directory where the script is, and then in each directory listed in `%PATH%` if it can't find it.

Comment: @SomethingDark No, the script and the file to be copied are in different locations on C. What you said sounds logical to me. But as I said above I was following the video (the link is also in the comments above) and the author did it just as I did and it worked for him. He saved his script to `c:\scripts`, but the file he copied was in the root of `c:\`

Comment: No, he clearly autocompleted, and you can see the file in the scripts directory when he's saving the script. The file and the script are in the same location.

Comment: @SomethingDark You're right he has "New Text Documents.txt" in his `c:\scripts`, but in the video he clearly talks about the one in the root (he even showed it in Explorer). Anyway, now everything is clear to me. The file he actually copied was the one from his scripts folder. SomethingDark, would you please post something as an answer or should I do it myself?

Comment: **Change the name of your script**, if you name it `Copy.bat`, each time you use the command `Copy`, it searches in the directory for any file named `Copy` and appends to it each of the extensions listed under the `%PathExt%` variable, _in the order listed_. As `.bat` is one of those it is finding itself.